# INSERT INTO desde una tabla a otra, evitando los id ya insertados

Tags: mysql

Alguien me podria ayuda, es que quisiera saber como insertar un `where` en un `insert into` en MySQL, lo intente realizar de esta manera pero me dice que

> La columna 'id_Tickets' en where clause es desconocida

Con el `WHERE` quiero que agregue los tickets pero que su `id_Tickets` sea diferente a `id` para que no se vuelvan a agregar todos, sino que solo los nuevos tickets.

```sql
INSERT INTO tickets (
    id_Tickets, is_active, customer, subject, status, priority, 
    category, assigned_agent, date_created, date_updated, agent_created, 
    ip_address, source, browser, os, add_recipients, prev_assignee, 
    date_closed, user_type, last_reply_on, last_reply_by, auth_code, 
    cust_24, cust_25, cust_26, cust_29, cust_30, cust_31, cust_32, 
    cust_33, cust_35
) 

SELECT id, is_active, customer, subject, status, priority, 
    category, assigned_agent, date_created, date_updated, agent_created, 
    ip_address, source, browser, os, add_recipients, prev_assignee, 
    date_closed, user_type, last_reply_on, last_reply_by, auth_code, 
    cust_24, cust_25, cust_26, cust_29, cust_30, cust_31, cust_32, 
    cust_33, cust_35
FROM wpam_psmsc_tickets t 
WHERE id_Tickets != t.id
```

Comment: Y que error te da?

Comment: "La columna 'id_Tickets' en where clause es desconocida " ese error me da

Comment: y si, porque no pertenece al select... vos estas queriendo comparar con el de la otra tabla.. pero a mysql esas cosas, no le gustan...

Comment: por favor, necesito soluciones no mas problemas :c   #humor

Comment: Si pero por desgracia, si tratas de poner un not in y hacer un query a la original, es muy probable que proteste... No se como solucionan estas cosas en mysql.. tu problema es claro, esperemos que alguien lo sepa hacer...

Comment: Si `tickets.id_Tickets` es *Llave Primaría* o *Única* no necesitas hacer nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Falla porque está intentando filtrar los datos de una columna que no existe en la tabla `wpam_psmsc_tickets` esto lo podemos solucionar de la siguiente manera:

- Haciendo uso de un LEFT JOIN, quedando la consulta de la siguiente manera:

```
INSERT INTO tickets (
    id_Tickets, is_active, customer, subject, status, priority, 
    category, assigned_agent, date_created, date_updated, agent_created, 
    ip_address, source, browser, os, add_recipients, prev_assignee, 
    date_closed, user_type, last_reply_on, last_reply_by, auth_code, 
    cust_24, cust_25, cust_26, cust_29, cust_30, cust_31, cust_32, 
    cust_33, cust_35
) 

SELECT id, is_active, customer, subject, status, priority, 
    category, assigned_agent, date_created, date_updated, agent_created, 
    ip_address, source, browser, os, add_recipients, prev_assignee, 
    date_closed, user_type, last_reply_on, last_reply_by, auth_code, 
    cust_24, cust_25, cust_26, cust_29, cust_30, cust_31, cust_32, 
    cust_33, cust_35
FROM wpam_psmsc_tickets t 
LEFT JOIN tickets tic
ON t.id = tic.id_Tickets
WHERE tic.id_Tickets IS NULL;
```

- Haciendo uso de una subquery:

```sql
INSERT INTO tickets (
    id_Tickets, is_active, customer, subject, status, priority, 
    category, assigned_agent, date_created, date_updated, agent_created, 
    ip_address, source, browser, os, add_recipients, prev_assignee, 
    date_closed, user_type, last_reply_on, last_reply_by, auth_code, 
    cust_24, cust_25, cust_26, cust_29, cust_30, cust_31, cust_32, 
    cust_33, cust_35
) 

SELECT id, is_active, customer, subject, status, priority, 
    category, assigned_agent, date_created, date_updated, agent_created, 
    ip_address, source, browser, os, add_recipients, prev_assignee, 
    date_closed, user_type, last_reply_on, last_reply_by, auth_code, 
    cust_24, cust_25, cust_26, cust_29, cust_30, cust_31, cust_32, 
    cust_33, cust_35
FROM wpam_psmsc_tickets t 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tickets WHERE tickets.id_Tickets = t.id)
```

Espero que te sirva y perdón de antemano si falla algo en la sintaxis, probe que esto funcionara para unas tablas con menos columnas que las tuyas, saludos.

Comment: Grande Grande!!!!!!!!!!! Muchas gracias brooooooooooooooooo